# How does my ajax call know where my json is in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a javascript file with some ajax in it as follows.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: 'data',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
           draw(data);
       },
       error: function (result) {
           error();
       }
   });
```

I also have created a method in a controller which renders json.

class GraphController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

```
def data
  render :json =>  User.select('value').map(&:value)
end
end
```

So my question is, how does rails know where the json is coming from especially as I'm not returning a physical file from my controller. What happens if I also have a physical .json file in my folder structure? Is there a heirarchy of how a view will look for a json file (eg physical file>jbuilder file>controller action)?

Comment: In your case output of `User.select('value').map(&:value)` is passed in json format itself you won't find any .json file are you looking to customize response json?

Comment: by specifying render :json=> User.select('value').map(&:value) rails will automatically pass the response in json format. if you want to build your json response in a specific format, then you can make use of jbuilder.

Comment: Rails would only serve a `.json` file (or any static file) if they are located in `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ajax call.. `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` defines what is the type of request you are querying with rails.`What that says is, "if the client wants HTML in response to this action, just respond as we would have before, but if the client wants XML, return them the list of people in XML format." (Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client.)`.

Take a look [respond_to api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) how rails responds to different types of request -js/xml/html/json

***so you can try this in your controller as well..edit the data action like this and try..any call to data such as js/html/xml/json will work and rails will understand what type of response it needs to send.***

```
def data

      format.html { redirect_to(user_list_url) }
      format.js
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users.to_xml(:include => @accounts) }
      format.json {render :json =>  User.select('value').map(&:value) }
end
```

**to render any error from controller to view..can be done like this:-**

```
   if @user.present?
       format.json {render :json =>  User.select('value').map(&:value) }  
   else
      format.js { render :json => @user.errors.full_messages.join(' '), 
:status => 400 }
    end
```

**use this in view in ajax.error function like this**

```
.error(function(data) {
                   $("#show_error").html("An Error Occurred,Please try again.");
                  });
```

HOPE THIS HELPS

Comment: That's nice. Thanks Milind. What about if I want to return the jbuilder json (it looks like a more versatile way of returning json

Comment: @SebastianZeki..i have edited my answer...if it helps you please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Every Action must render something.
Either you render something explicitly or rails will look for a page with name similar to the action in inside respective controller's folder in views. 
You may render an html.erb, .json, .haml etc from views( provided you specify respond to format)

If you are rendering someting explicitly (which is true in your case, as json) Rails wont bother to look into views folder.

Or otherwise you may just skip `render :json`  statement and specify that object in .json file, with respond to :json.

Here in your scenario, you are rendering a json object, which will be accepted in the `success:` section of the AJAX function's *data* arguement.

Comment: Ok but then a)how do I refer to it in the ajax shown? Do I call it the action name as in url: 'data' and b) if I create json in jbuilder then do I leave the controller action blank and then how do I refer to that in the ajax call? Confused.....

Comment: First Question: in url u can type `graphs/data` `controller/action`, and don;t forget to define it in routes.
Second Question: There are two things, If are going with explicit rending from action itself then I think jbuilder won't be needed, but If that object is big enough then jbuilder is a good option. This http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks Karan. I've seen that video but the one thing it doesnt talk about is how to call the jbuilder json from ajax. How would I call it? Do I still use url:data but make sure the jbuilder file is in the same folder as the data view (and call it data.json.jbuilder)?

Comment: Try out both the approaches :)